# Update more than one row getting max value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table.

```
ID       SID     CID      Number
----------------------------------
1237      1       5        NULL
1236      1       5        NULL
1235      1       NULL      2
1234      1       NULL      2
1233      1       NULL      1
1232      1       NULL      1
```

I want to get max Number value. And Update Number column which is NULL

```
DECLARE @Number INT;
SELECT @Number =  max([Number]) FROM STACKOVERFLOW WHERE [Number] IS NOT NULL AND SID = 1
SELECT @Number
```

This SQL statement will return 2.

As I said, I want to update number column which is `null` but it should be `"maximum value of number column"` + 1, that is to say in my case it should be 3.

```
DECLARE SID INT = 1;

UPDATE STACKOVERFLOW 
SET
Number = (
          SELECT TOP 1 CASE 
          WHEN Number IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE @Number + 1 END 
          FROM STACKOVERFLOW 
          WHERE SID = @SID AND Number IS NULL
         )
FROM STACKOVERFLOW WHERE ID = 1237
```

The table will be like below:

```
ID       SID     CID      Number
----------------------------------
1237      1       5         3
1236      1       5        NULL
1235      1       NULL      2
1234      1       NULL      2
1233      1       NULL      1
1232      1       NULL      1
```

After that, when again sql statement works for `ID = 1236`  and at that time @Number will return 3 and 
the record will be like below.

```
ID       SID     CID      Number
----------------------------------
.
1236      1       5        4
.
.
```

But the result that I want is

```
ID       SID     CID      Number
----------------------------------
.
1236      1       5      3
.
```

At the end of operations the table should be like

```
ID       SID     CID      Number
----------------------------------
1237      1       5         3
1236      1       5         3
1235      1       NULL      2
1234      1       NULL      2
1233      1       NULL      1
1232      1       NULL      1
1231      2       5         5
1230      2       5         5
1229      2       NULL      4
1228      2       NULL      4
```

Any idea? 
Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE STACKOVERFLOW
   SET Number = (SELECT MAX(number) + 1 FROM STACKOVERFLOW WHERE SID = 1)
 WHERE Number IS NULL
   AND SID = 1
```

Then do the same thing for SID = 2

```
UPDATE STACKOVERFLOW
   SET Number = (SELECT MAX(number) + 1 FROM STACKOVERFLOW WHERE SID = 2)
 WHERE Number IS NULL
   AND SID = 2
```

Or to make it a bit more elegant:

```
UPDATE STACKOVERFLOW
   SET Number = (SELECT MAX(number) + 1 FROM STACKOVERFLOW WHERE SID = A.SID)
  FROM STACKOVERFLOW A
 WHERE Number IS NULL
```

Comment: but when I update first, Number will be 3 but for another row that statement will return 4, is not it?

Comment: No. With MS SQL you need to start thinking in result sets, not single execution.

Comment: Yes I qualified it with an id.. because there will be another SID value for example SID = 2 and it will have another Number values.. so I have to qualified it, isn't it?

Comment: No. If you want the results above you run the query exactly how it is. That's why I was saying you have to think in result sets not in individual rows.

Comment: I edited the part of my question "At the end of operations the table should be like..."
If I use select max it will return 5... but I want to update the value where SID = 1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16466/discussion-between-grixxly-and-stack-user)

Comment: I wrote someting but it was not sent in chat room

Comment: Apparently chat isn't working. Show what your table looks like before the update statement. Your end result has more rows then the initial table.

Comment: ID       SID     CID      Number
----------------------------------
1237      1       5         NULL
1236      1       5         NULL
1235      1       NULL      2
1234      1       NULL      2
1233      1       NULL      1
1232      1       NULL      1
1231      2       5         NULL
1230      2       5         NULL
1229      2       NULL      4
1228      2       NULL      4
1227      2       NULL      3
1226      2       NULL      3
1225      2       NULL      2
1224      2       NULL      2
1223      2       NULL      1
1222      2       NULL      1

Table is like this.

Comment: on the other hand, at the same time 2 different SID can have same Number

Comment: Based on the data I believe ID's 1230, 1231, 1236, and 1237 should have 5 as their number and the above SQL produces that result.

Comment: yes according to your sql statement you are right but only it should be like below:
1237      1       5         3
1236      1       5         3
there wont be any changes except for them.. because I want to update only where SID = 1

Comment: you are right. but I dont want to update all SID values only I have to update SID = 1

Comment: The the first query, where SID = 1 will take care of that for you. If you needed to update SID = 2 or any SID for that matter the last query would do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Either set all at once or also check CID for NULL